# Помогите найти 2-й способ решения задачи

Tags: java

Задание:

> В тексте найти и напечатать n символов, встречающихся наиболее часто.
>   Указать сколько раз встречается каждый из n символов. n - произвольно
>   задаваемое число.

```
public class FindSymbolsInTheText {
    public static String calculateWordsEnding(String string) {
        int count1 = 0; // а
        int count2 = 0; // е
        int count3 = 0; // в
        int count4 = 0; // и
        int count5 = 0; // к
        int count6 = 0; // л
        int count7 = 0; // м
        int count8 = 0; // о

        string = string.toLowerCase();
        for (int i = 0; i<string.length(); i++) {
            if (string.charAt(i) == 'а')
                count1++;
            if (string.charAt(i) == 'е')
                count2++;
            if (string.charAt(i) == 'в')
                count3++;
            if (string.charAt(i) == 'и')
                count4++;
            if (string.charAt(i) == 'к')
                count5++;
            if (string.charAt(i) == 'л')
                count6++;
            if (string.charAt(i) == 'м')
                count7++;
            if (string.charAt(i) == 'о')
                count8++;
        }

        System.out.println("а = " + count1 + "\n" + "е = " + count2 + "\n" + "в = " + count3 + "\n" + "и = " + count4 + "\n" +
            "к = " + count5 + "\n" + "л = " + count6 + "\n" + "м = " + count7 + "\n" + "о = " + count8 + "\n");

        return string;
    }

    private static String readingFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        return new String(encoded, "utf-8");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используя **[HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)** можно занести данные в виде ключ-значение. Где ключ - символ, значение - количество повторений.

```
String str = "testtest123yot";

HashMap<Character, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (hm.get(str.charAt(i)) != null) {
        int temp = hm.get(str.charAt(i));
        hm.put(str.charAt(i), ++temp);
    } else {
        hm.put(str.charAt(i), 1);
    }
}
```

Останется взять только наиболее встречающиеся (отсортировать по значениям `Integer` и взять первые `N`).

---

Так и быть дополню сортировку по значениям в *Java8*

```
Map<Character, Integer> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();

hm.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<Character, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
        .forEachOrdered(x -> result.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));

System.out.println(result);
```

где `hm` - Hashmap c символами и их количеством

Answer (score 3):

И ещё один вариант с использованием stream-ов:

```
String str = "testtest123yot33322aaaaaaaa";
int n = 6;
str.chars()
        .mapToObj(e -> e)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .sorted((e1, e2) -> (int)(e2.getValue() - e1.getValue()))
        .limit(n)
        .forEach(e -> System.out.println((char)(int)e.getKey() + " - " + e.getValue()));
```

- `chars` - получение потока кодов символов (`IntStream`) из строки
- `mapToObj` - преобразование `IntStream` в `Stream<Integer>` (для последующей группировки)
- `collect` - подсчет количества вхождений каждого символа
- `entrySet().stream()` - переход к потоку пар "код символа"-"количество"
- `sorted` - сортировка (по убыванию количества вхождений)
- `limit` - ограничение количества результирующих записей
- `forEach` - вывод на экран

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще с помощью Java 8 Stream API сразу собрать в `Map<Charter, count>`

```
char[] chars =
        "dmsonmcsoianviavnSVNSDVNwdklnvsjlkdvndvnsdvnlsdldnvos v ndslnsionvdlksvnsonvdlkvnwoinvslkdnv"
            .toCharArray();

    Map<Character, Long> collect = IntStream.range(0, chars.length)
        .mapToObj(i -> chars[i])
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));

    System.out.println(collect.get('n'));
```

вывод: `16`

Comment: "напечатать n символов, встречающихся наиболее часто"

Comment: @Denis там ещё количество вхождений каждого символа надо вывести, насколько я понял.

Comment: @Denis точно. забыл про это